# Taylor expansion of the differential change of vectors between points on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

This is a probably very basic question about the Taylor series

$$\begin{align}
X^\alpha\,(x + \delta x) &= X^\alpha (x)+\delta x^b\;\partial_bX^\alpha+\cdots\\[2ex]
&=X^\alpha(x) + \delta x^b\;\frac{\partial X^\alpha}{\partial x^b}+\cdots\\[2ex]
&= X^\alpha(x) + \delta X^\alpha + \cdots
\end{align}$$

corresponding to a diagram such as

[image]

and introduced in the exposition of the covariant derivative at [this point](https://youtu.be/hK3lt6ovgYc?t=18m17s) of a lecture on tensors by XylyXylyX
.

So the very basic question is why is the expression above the Taylor expansion. I don't see the value of $X^\alpha(x + \delta x)$ as the first component, for example. And the first derivative doesn't seem to include $X^\alpha(x).$

Comment: What's the exact question?

Comment: I edited the OP. As I said, it's probably too basic for the forum...

Comment: Suppose we have a function $f(x)$. If x changes by a **small** amount $\delta x$, then $f(x)$ also changes by a tiny amount, given by $\delta f=\frac{df}{dx}\delta x$. Here $X^\alpha$ is a function of all the components $x_a$, and this is a Taylor expansion in multidimentional calculus.

Comment: @SayanMandal Thanks. Comparing to $f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}+\cdots$, the first term in the Taylor series is the value of the function evaluated at $a$,  i.e. $f(a)$ in regular calculus,  and here it would be evaluated at $x,$ not $x+ \delta x,$ right... And the expression $\delta x^b\frac{\partial X^\alpha}{\partial x^b}$ is also the first derivative evaluated at $a$ with $x-a=\delta x^b,$ and $\frac{f'(a)}{1!}= \frac{\partial X^\alpha}{\partial x^b} ,$ correct?

Comment: Right. In this case $x$ taken on the role of $a$ in your more familiar examples of Taylor Series. Also, I am sure you have realized that in the second term there is a sum over the index $b$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66721/discussion-between-sayan-mandal-and-toni).